# Return Largest 3-Digit Chunk From String - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, numbers

I don't understand why this is returning zero:

```js
function largestOfThree (num) {
    let stringyNums = num.toString();
    let highest = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i <= stringyNums.length - 3; i++) {
        let chunk = stringyNums.slice(i, i + 3);
        console.log(chunk);
        if (chunk > highest) chunk = highest;
    }
    return highest;
}
console.log(largestOfThree(123456789));
```

It seems as though `chunk` is not getting assigned to `highest`. I want to assign the new chunk to highest as we're looping through the `stringyNums`, every time it's greater than the existing `highest` chunk.

The function should return `789`, in this case.

Comment: If `chunk` is a string, what does `chunk > highest` actually do?

Comment: Ah - need to use `.parseInt()`, maybe.

Comment: `highest = chunk` instead of `chunk = highest`

Comment: I don't know if that is the issue, but it is a potential thing to be careful with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting `highest` to `chunk`
Change

```
if (chunk > highest) chunk = highest;
```

To

```
if (chunk > highest) highest = chunk ;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because of this line

```
if (chunk > highest) chunk = highest;
```

You're assigning chunk to highest instead of assigning highest to the largest chunk. Simply reverse the two variables and you're good to go.

```
if (chunk > highest) highest = chunk;
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference you can accomplish this with a more readable form of a one-liner (6-liner?):

```js
const largestOfThree = num =>
  num
  .toString()
  .match(/.{1,3}/g)
  .map(Number)
  .reduce((acc, curr) => (acc > curr ? acc : curr));

console.log(largestOfThree(123456789));
```

Comment: Nice (+1) but one could quibble with this being described as a "one-liner". I count 6.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You are assigning `chunk=highest` which is wrong

```
function largestOfThree (num) {

    let stringyNums = num.toString();
    let highest = 0; 
    for (let i = 0; i <= stringyNums.length - 3; i++) {

        let chunk = stringyNums.slice(i, i + 3);
        console.log(chunk);
        if (chunk > highest) highest=chunk; <---the error was here

    }

    return highest;

}

console.log(largestOfThree(123456789));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
largestOfThree(num: number): number {
    const stringyNums = num.toString();
    let highest = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= stringyNums.length - 3; i++) {
      let chunk = parseInt(stringyNums.slice(i, i + 3));
      if (chunk > highest) highest = chunk;
    }
    return highest;
}
```